# Unable to save colors changed with the color picker in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

New note: It seems ok in FireFox and Safari. And it seems ok in Chrome in new instances of Mac and Windows at BrowserStack. But it's happening in Chrome on my Mac. But it's not happening just to me. It's happening to several people.

Suddenly I am unable to save colors manually set with the color picker in tinyMCE. It had been working fine before. Clicking the Save button just doesn't do anything. Please see the video capture for an example.
[Color Selector Not Saving](https://photos.app.goo.gl/EB2P45tQhS3rE3PL9)

I had a version of tinymceInit() that did work. But now it's not working there either. Clicking the Save button seems to cause an error in the JavaScript console:

```
theme.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: r.unshift is not a function
    at Object.add (theme.min.js:4)
    at jb (theme.min.js:4)
    at theme.min.js:4
    at Object.each (theme.min.js:4)
    at theme.min.js:4
    at Object.r [as onSubmit] (theme.min.js:4)
    at theme.min.js:4
    at theme.min.js:4
    at theme.min.js:4
    at Object.each (theme.min.js:4)
```

The `theme.min.js` file is served from cdn.tiny.cloud.

Comparing the two tinymceInit() functions these are the only lines that are different:

Previously working old version, but now it's getting the same error:

```
plugins: ["advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor","searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen","insertdatetime media table paste help"],
menubar: 'format table tools help',
toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect  | forecolor | bold italic fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent  | link image | code | help',
```

New version - it was also working and has started getting this error:

```
  plugins: ["advlist autolink lists link image imagetools charmap print preview anchor autoresize","searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen","insertdatetime media table paste help"],
  autoresize_bottom_margin: 10,
  imagetools_toolbar: 'imageoptions',   
  menubar: 'format table',
  toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | styleselect  | forecolor | bold italic fontsizeselect | numlist bullist alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | code',
  fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt',
  link_assume_external_targets: 'http',
  default_link_target: '_blank',
```

Any idea of what might be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was working in other browsers. It was working in an Incognito window in Chrome. Clearing the cache didn't work. Relaunching Chrome didn't work. So I tried clearing the cookies and site data just for the site with a problem. That worked!

Something got "stuck" from some old cookies or old site data. What happened remains a mystery though.

Comment: That's good to know you fixed it! So you mean this library has a cache structure or your project has. Right?

Comment: I guess the library does. I still don't understand what happened. It seems like a library bug somewhere, leaving something that blocked the UI until what was left was cleared.

Comment: Somebody at Git said they were able to replicate the bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems working like [this](https://codepen.io/denizhacisalihoglu/pen/GRrOYrY). Is there anything different from your side?

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea#full-featured-non-premium",
  plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image imagetools charmap print preview anchor autoresize",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table paste help"
  ],
  autoresize_bottom_margin: 10,
  imagetools_toolbar: "imageoptions",
  imagetools_cors_hosts: ["picsum.photos"],
  menubar: "format table",
  toolbar:
    "undo redo | link image | styleselect  | forecolor | bold italic fontsizeselect | numlist bullist alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | code",
  fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt",
  link_assume_external_targets: "http",
  default_link_target: "_blank"
});
```

Comment: In my case the JavaScript error I mentioned occurred when trying to save the color - until I cleared the cookies and site data cached for the site. I don't know what the problem data was though.

Comment: I see. Browser might cached the older version of the library. Cache clearing can be a countable solution.

Comment: What's odd is that it had been working. And then it stopped working. And then clearing the cache had it working again. Just for that feature. With two different setups of tinymce.init(). On two separate servers. Could it be a bug was introduced into the cloud version of tinyMCE, the browser picked up something during the bug, and then had to be cache cleared after the bug was fixed? I wonder if serving tinyMCE locally instead of via the cloud might be more stable?

Comment: And it happened again on one of the servers. I cleared the cache again and the issue went away. The problem is just with that one feature - clicking save to save an entered text color. I haven't seen it with any other feature.

Comment: That sounds weird. But moving local could be good. I understand this is a premium feature. That may cause the error. Do you think so?

Comment: What do you think is a premium feature? I think all the plugins I'm using are just the open source version. And running local is also ok for open source.

Comment: There are some premium features i believed in regarding this page: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/#fullfeaturedincludingpremiumplugins

Comment: I've confirmed that I am just using open source plugins, no premium features.